# error: undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'

Tags: java, c++, qt-creator

I'm trying to get my first c++/java to work using Qt Creator but I have an error, which is produced by the following line of code

```
jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

> error: undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'

Some online posts suggested to add

> LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/lib/" -ljvm

to the .pro but it doesn't make a difference.

I also tried

> LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/lib/jvm.lib" -ljvm

I didn't receive undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12' but I got a different error

> error: cannot find -ljvm

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Do you tried `Add Library-> External library` in Qt Creator?

Comment: I did and I got a different error. Cannot open include file: 'jni_md.h'

Comment: I installed jdk x86. I changed INCLUDEPATH ad LIBS in the .pro file to x86 not the jdk 64 and now I get  error: cannot find -ljvm.lib